# Excel UDF takes empty parameter in unwanted second invocation

Tags: c#, excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-addins

In my project the argument of one UDF is the result of another UDF function.

For example:

```
GetPeriod(string name, string date) {
           // logic 
          }

Data(string name, string period) {
          // logic
          }
```

I am using these UDF in two different cells as

```
cell a1: =GetPeriod("KMP", "27-12-18")
cell a3: =Data(a$1,"KMP")
```

I am using the result of one UDF (GetPeriod) as a parameter in another UDF(Data).

The issue here is the Data UDF is triggered twice: one time with the actual result, and one time with empty value of cell A1.

I tried setting calculation mode to manual, but it still gets invoked twice.

Is there any possible problem with this design or is there any way to set up the precedence in UDF so that Excel understands which UDF to trigger first?

Comment: Have you tried making the cell reference parameter into a range parameter? (Assuming vba coding)

Comment: @Mistella No i am not sure about the VBA coding. I am writing this addin in c#. But can you give the sample code in VBA to do that. I'll try to convert it into c#.

Comment: @Mistella Did you meant passing the range like this "=Data(a$1:a$1, "KMP")" ? Still it's getting triggered twice.

Comment: With the cell selected, go to the Formula ribbon and click on Evaluate Formula under the Formula Auditing group. It will let you step through the calculations and see how Excel is evaluating it. See if you can spot where the error is when doing that.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how VBA code translate to c# for Excel, so I'll try to give a comprehensive explanation/example.

---

In VBA, there are two main ways to pass a reference for an excel cell (or Range) to a UDF.

1. Using a string parameter (i.e. `Data(name as String)`)
2. Using a Range Object parameter (i.e. `Data(name as Range)` or more broadly `Data(name as Object)`)

When the string parameter is used, the range's value is usually accessed in the code via `Worksheet("Name").Range("String Param")).Value`. When the object parameter is used, the code generally looks like `RangeParam.Value`.

There are also times when a range is hard-coded into or indirectly referenced by a UDF. I would avoid doing this; especially if that range contains a formula.

---

When Excel is doing calculations, it performs multiple steps.

1. Initiate calculations in each cell to determine the range parameters. (This is used to determine dependencies.)
2. Create the dependency tree with the proper order of calculations.
3. Do the finalized calculations in the determined order.

The important things to understand from this are:

- If a range is referenced via a string parameter, Excel may not understand the dependency.
- If a range is referenced in the calculation, but hardcoded in, indirectly referenced, or otherwise not passed in as a parameter, Excel will not understand the dependency.
- If the UDF will get differing results depending on the number of times it's run, then there will be unexpected results (from Excel's multi-step dependency-determinations).

---

A few other notes:

If an error occurs in a UDF, how that's dealt with can vary a tad between whether the UDF being used in the worksheet or whether it's being called via other code.

I don't think you'll be able to prevent Excel from running the calculation twice, as that's part of how it's determining dependencies (unless I'm completely misunderstanding what you wrote). However, I would also expect that the calculation with the empty value of `A1` would occur **before** the final calculation value with the actual result. If the second (final) calculation result is the one with the blank `A1`, then I'm not sure what to tell you, besides checking that all cells/ranges being referenced in a UDF are being passed into that UDF as parameter objects.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that cell A3 is empty before you insert the UDF into cell A1.  The only way that the "Data" UDF gets called is if it already exists in the sheet you're adding it to.  To clarify - If there is no formula in cell A3, then there's no way the "Data" UDF can get called.  But changing the value in cell A1 by inserting the "Period" UDF will trigger the formula in cell A3 to recalculate, since one of the parameters being passed into it just got changed.
Another option would predicated on needing just the values and not the actual UDFs in the cells.  In that case simply set the ".Value2" of the cells using the "Data" and "Period" functions, passing the "Period" value as a function into the "Data" function.

```
Range rngPeriod; //Set to cell "A1"
Range rngDate; //Set to cell "A3"
rngPeriod.Value2 = GetPeriod("KMP", "27-12-18");
rngData.Value2 =Data(GetPeriod("KMP", "27-12-18"),"KMP");
```